# custom animation in ursina engine

Tags: python, module, game-engine

I am trying to play my own animation in the ursina engine but I have no idea how to. According to the documentation, I would need this code:

```
    from ursina import *

    app = Ursina()
    window.color = color._20

    animation = Animation('ursina_wink', fps=2, scale=1, filtering=None, autoplay=True)
    EditorCamera()
    app.run()
```

And that one does indeed work. However, I do not understand how I can replace the default animation with my own frames ('ursina_wink' is inbuilt).

The documentation says there is a frame parameter, so here is what I tried so far:

```
    from ursina import *
    
    app = Ursina()
    window.color = color._20
    coin1 = load_texture('animation/coin1')
    coin2 = load_texture('animation/coin2')
    coin3 = load_texture('animation/coin3')
    coin4 = load_texture('animation/coin4')
    coin5 = load_texture('animation/coin5')
    coin6 = load_texture('animation/coin6')
    
    animation = Animation('test',fps=2, scale=1, filtering=None, autoplay=True, frames = (coin1, coin2,coin3,coin4,coin5,coin6))
    EditorCamera()
    app.run()
```

But I cannot see anything on the screen and I cannot find an example online for it. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

It loads an image sequence as a frame animation. You can load it like this:
`Animation('coin')` and it will take all the frames starting with 'coin' and load them alphabetically.

I will clarify this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across your error and I have a simple solution, try to convert the images into a gif because in the ursina documentation it says that you can also use a gif wich is way more simple but less customizable, here's the text:

```
Loads an image sequence as a frame animation.
Consider using SpriteSheetAnimation instead if possible.
So if you have some frames named image_000.png, image_001.png, image_002.png and so on,
you can load it like this: Animation('image')

You can also load a .gif by including the file type: Animation('image.gif')
```

So, I hope this helped you.