# Destroy a Animator object ursina

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

I have an animator object in ursina. I want to destroy it.

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
walka = Animation("assets/zombies/zombie1/walk/",fps = 5,loop=True)
animator1 =  Animator(animations= {"walk":walka})
animator1.state = "walk"
destroy(animator1)
app.run()
```

This doesn't seem to work and throws this error:
`AttributeError: 'Animator' object has no attribute 'eternal'`

Comment: I'm not sure where the error comes from (could be an oversight in Ursina) but you could try to manually set `animator1.eternal = False`

Comment: @JanWilamowski after adding this , it gives me this error ```AttributeError: 'Animator' object has no attribute 'children'```

Comment: Adding `animator1.children = []` should do the trick. The issue seems to be that the `destroy()` code assumes the existence of several attributes: https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/18b8d6e3f4df3c0c4b3cdfcf8616510706fbd7d3/ursina/ursinastuff.py#L55

Comment: It might be worth raising an issue at https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/issues

Comment: @JanWilamowski it is giving this error now : ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'finish'``` But I will raise an issue on github. Thank you

Comment: yeah, it looks like the `destroy()` function isn't compatible with animations yet. You could implement your own version, based on the one I linked.

Comment: @JanWilamowski i can't understand how he destroys it, can you tell me to what should I edit the destroy function

Comment: The last error you got occurs because `_destroy()` iterators over the keys of `entity.animations` rather than its values, presumably because it used to be a list at some point. You can iterate yourself and call `.finish()` and `.kill()` on all your animations.

Comment: @JanWilamowski is there a  way to add an animation as an texture to an entity??? So that i can delete that entity

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060290/custom-animation-in-ursina-engine and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130756/show-image-on-screen-with-ursina/68147680#68147680

Comment: @JanWilamowski i can't just add parent=camera.ui, because my game wouldn't run accordingly

Comment: That might not be necessary. Why do you want to destroy the object before running the app anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()
walka = Animation("assets/zombies/zombie1/walk/", fps=5, loop=True)
animator1 = Animator(animations={"walk": walka})
animator1.state = "walk"
walka.disable() # disables the animation.

app.run()
```